# How to display dataframe in window using Rcaller

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I am trying to display dataframe in a file using Rcaller library in java. But it seems does not work.
The following code is what I'm trying to do:

```
   RCaller caller = new RCaller();
   RCode code = new RCode(); 
   code.addRCode("a=table(data$rate, predArbreDecision)");  


   File file = code.startPlot();
   code.addRCode("as.data.frame.matrix(a)");
   caller.runOnly();
   ImageIcon ii = code.getPlot(file);
   code.showPlot(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

In RCaller the methods **startPlot()** and **endPlot()** work like their R counterparts like png(), pdf(), bmp() for starting a file device and **dev.off()** for finalizing the plot.

After using the **startPlot()** you should plot something using R's graphics functions.

This very basic examples will give an idea for generating plots using RCaller:

```
  double[] numbers = new double[]{1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10};

  code.addDoubleArray("x", numbers);

  File file = code.startPlot();
  System.out.println("Plot will be saved to : " + file);

  code.addRCode("plot(x, pch=19)");

  code.endPlot();
```

This example creates a double array of values 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10 and pass them to R using the method addDoubleArray. The method startPlot returns a File object which is possibly created in your temp directory. The usual R expression

```
plot(x, pch=19)
```

draws a plot, but this time not on the screen but in the generated file by method **startPlot()**.

After calling the method endPlot() we can finalize the process by calling

```
caller.runOnly();
```

so all the directives are converted to R code and passed to R. Now we can show the content in Java:

```
code.showPlot(file);
```

Here is the whole example:

```
try {
  RCaller caller = RCaller.create();

  RCode code = RCode.create();


  double[] numbers = new double[]{1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10};

  code.addDoubleArray("x", numbers);
  File file = code.startPlot();
  System.out.println("Plot will be saved to : " + file);
  code.addRCode("plot(x, pch=19)");
  code.endPlot();


  caller.setRCode(code);
  System.out.println(code.getCode().toString());

  caller.runOnly();
  code.showPlot(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Logger.getLogger(SimplePlot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
}
```

You can see the links for the example given here and further reading:

[Basic plotting using RCaller](https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller/blob/master/RCaller/src/main/java/examples/SimplePlot.java)

[Journal research paper](http://www.sciencedomain.org/download/NDgzOEBAcGY.pdf)

[Unpublished research paper for RCaller 3](https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller/blob/master/doc/rcaller3/rcaller3.pdf)